# Firebase onSnapshot listener: How to handle if doc does not exist yet?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app where users can tag subjects they are interested in.

I am looking for best practices on how to handle the following issue:

I have a page that mounts an onSnapshot listener during page creation (example page path: `site.com/tags/apple`). This page allows the user to actually add the tag to their feed. First, I need to "watch" whether they add the tag to their feed or check to see if it already exists so that way I can toggle the state of a button icon to let them know that they already have added this tag to their feed.

I thought I'd use the `onSnapshot` listener to handle this logic like so (simplified for this question):

```
mounted() {

    loadwatchedTag() {
      const docRef = doc(db, `users/${this.userProfile.uid}/tags`, 'apple') //<-- example tag

      this.unsubscribe = onSnapshot(docRef, {
        next: (doc) => console.log('tag', doc.data()),
        error: (error) =>
          console.log('watchedTag listener error', error)
      })
    }

}
```

The problem is that on page load, I get the following error in console (because the tag does not yet exist):

`tag, undefined`

So, how to handle this issue on page load if the tag does not yet exist? Should I be doing something like this within the onSnapshot code?

```
if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("tag exists!", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("tag does not exist");
}
```

Comment: So, if `doc.data()` is `undefined` you can just use `doc.data() == undefined`

Answer (score 2):

> Should I be doing something like this within the `onSnapshot` code?
>
> ```
> if (docSnap.exists()) {
>    console.log("tag exists!", docSnap.data());
> } else {   
>    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case  
>    console.log("tag does not exist"); 
> }
> ```

Yes this is exactly what you should do. And there is a "Note" dedicated to this case in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) for the `getDoc()` method:

> Note: If there is no document at the location referenced by `docRef`,
> the resulting document will be empty and calling `exists` on it will
> return false.

Comment: Thanks! I will research and get back to you.